# Oracle Update statement with ORA-00913 error

Tags: sql, oracle

I am in the process of updating two columns in a table called "sample" with values 5, if these conditions satisfies;

1) If `TABLE A.MEM_NBR = TABLE B.MEM_NBR AND TABLE B.M_ID = XXXX, AND TABLE B.CLCL = 1` and finally using a join condition like TABLE `A.ID = SAMPLE.ID`
2) If these conditions do not suffice, then we need not update the table.

But I am getting an error;

```
SQL Error: ORA-00913: too many values 
00913. 00000 - "too many values".
```

Need some help on the above update script, as to where i am going wrong.

The script that i am using is as follows;

```
UPDATE SAMPLE 
SET SAMPLE.PCB = 5, SAMPLE.PCBP_Q = 5 
WHERE (
    SELECT * 
    FROM MEMBER_A A,S_NEW B 
    WHERE A.MEM_NBR = B.MEM_NBR 
        AND B.M_ID = 1111 
        AND B.CLCL = 1 
        AND B.ID = C.ID);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your subquery can return more than one value. To get around this problem you can use the `EXISTS` keyword. (I also converted the join to ANSI syntax.)

```
UPDATE SAMPLE C
SET C.PCB = 5, C.PCBP_Q = 5 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM 
        MEMBER_A A
        JOIN S_NEW B 
        ON A.MEM_NBR = B.MEM_NBR 
        AND B.M_ID = 1111 
        AND B.CLCL = 1 
    WHERE 
        A.ID = C.ID);
```

Comment: Just a doubt, how is the subquery linked with the outer table SAMPLE? I think it will update all records in SAMPLE if the inner query has any result. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @San this is perfect. I assume you are not convinced that join in UPDATE like this will behave properly. I had this too once.. the update happens based on every row in the sourcetable check in exists of subqueried table.

Comment: @San: thank you for your comment. The subquery and outer query are linked in the `A.ID = C.ID` condition. (This was not clear in the OP's code because the table alias was not consistent.)

Answer (score 0):

Your where condition might be wrong. It lead to match many values without mapping

Try like this

```
UPDATE SAMPLE 
SET SAMPLE.PCB = 5, SAMPLE.PCBP_Q = 5 
WHERE ColumnNmae IN (
    SELECT ColumnName 
    FROM MEMBER_A A,S_NEW B 
    WHERE A.MEM_NBR = B.MEM_NBR 
        AND B.M_ID = 1111 
        AND B.CLCL = 1 
        AND B.ID = C.ID);
```

Or use a correlated subquery like this:

```
UPDATE SAMPLE 
SET SAMPLE.PCB = 5, SAMPLE.PCBP_Q = 5 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM MEMBER_A A,S_NEW B 
    WHERE A.MEM_NBR = B.MEM_NBR 
        AND B.M_ID = 1111 
        AND B.CLCL = 1 
        AND B.ID = C.ID
        AND A.ColumnNmae = SAMPLE.ColumnNmaes);
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply back. This script works pretty well for me. Adding to it, I have around 8 similar (a bit different update scripts), and i want to run all of them into a single scripts. Should i use a Package/ Procedure, so that all the 8 similar scripts can be execute at once? Please suggest me what and how to do it.

Comment: I am in the process of using the same above query, but this time, it has to update the date fields. I am using this query, but it wont work. Any thoughts or suggestion as to what is wrong here; 'UPDATE SAMPLE C
SET SAMPLE.C_DATE = TO_DATE('01/01/2013','MM/DD/YYYY') and TO_DATE('12/31/2013','MM/DD/YYYY')
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT *
    FROM MEMBER_A A, S_NEW B
      WHERE A.MEM_NBR = B.MEM_NBR
        AND B.M_ID IN (1111,2222,3333)
        AND A.L_TEST = TO_DATE('01/01/2013','MM/DD/YYYY') and TO_DATE('12/31/2013','MM/DD/YYYY')
        AND B.ID = C.ID);'